# AX 2012 RDP Class report

Tags: reporting-services, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I am having trouble getting user selected values, my parm methods of contract class returns nothing, tried changing contract class, restarted ssrs service, incremental cil, deleted & redeployed report but no luck.
here is my parm method of contract class:

```
    [DataMemberAttribute("AssetGroupId")]
public AssetGroupId parmAssetGroupId(AssetGroupId _assetGroupId = assetGroupId)
{
    assetGroupId = _assetGroupId;
    return assetGroupId;
}
```

and here is part of my process report function:

```
public void processReport()
{
    PhcFixedAssetRegisterRptContract contract;
    AssetGroupId _assetGroupId;
    AssetId _assetId;
breakpoint;
    super();

    contract = this.parmDataContract() as PhcFixedAssetRegisterRptContract;
    _assetGroupId = contract.parmAssetGroupId();
    _assetId = contract.parmAssetId();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what went wrong, but i restarted my computer and issue resolved, it was a developer machine so SSRS, AOS, DB Server all is setup on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Assure that you have the [SRSReportParameterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/srsreportparameterattribute.new.aspx) for your Data Provider

```cs
[SRSReportParameterAttribute(classStr(PhcFixedAssetRegisterRptContract))]
class MyDataProvider extends SRSReportDataProviderBase
{
    public void processReport()
    {
    }
}
```

Also do a *Refresh* on the Dataset for this Report Data Provider in the Report Designer and publish the report. Then go to AX AOT and do *Restore* command on this report.